# How can I disable default +t channel mode in ircd-hybrid?

Tags: debian, irc

I have a Debian server running ircd-hybrid, which gives every new channel `+t` flag, meaning that only channel operators can change channel topic. This is not very practical, since we use operator privileges very rarely and makes it complicated to set topic.

Is there any way how can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bot to change or unlock the topic. Try http://supybot.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, it is rather frustrating to have to use another piece of software to work around the fact that the damned thing should be allow to do this in the first place.

Comment: Agreed, annoying.  I am successfully using the Topic supybot plugin.  With that installed and configured, you can run "supybot topic unlock" to set -t in the channel.  Silly that the server software itself doesn't support this :-(

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any way to do this in the example config files or any mention of it being possible anywhere in the limited documentation. That leaves patching and compiling from source as the only way I can determine.

Comment: :/ For the record, in ircd-hybrid-7.2.3 the hardcoded default seems to be on line 247 of `modules/core/m_join.c`.